# Как расширить массив на основе другого массива?

Tags: javascript

```js
var array1 = [
 {name: "dima"}
];

var array2 = [
 {
   name: "dima",
    age: 22,
    notes: "test0"
  },
  {
   name: "oleg",
    age: 27,
    notes: "test1"
  },
  {
   name: "vasja",
    age: 44,
    notes: "test2"
  }
];
```

Как сделать чтобы первый массив расширил себя используя значения второго массива? 
То есть мне нужно сделать, чтобы было вот так.

```js
var array1 = [
      {
      name: "dima",
      age: 22,
      notes: "test0"
      }
];
```

И нужно чтобы это работало с другими значениями, то есть если у нас в первом массиве другой name, то нужно чтобы брались свойства из второго массива у которого такой же name. Как такое  сделать?

Comment: Попытайтесь использовать циклы.

Comment: Отсутствующие в первом массиве элементы (в данном случае `array2[1]` и `array2[2]`) - копироваться не должны?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Так как мы имеем дело с объектами, оператором присваивания `=` их "копировать" будет неразумно: потому что это будет не копирование, а создание в массиве `array1` референсных ссылок на объекты в элементах `array2` (т.е., первый массив фактически не будет содержать присвоенные таким образом объекты).

Для **копирования** полей объекта, разумно использовать один из следующих способов (на них список не заканчивается, но эти два - основные):

- рекурсивную функцию: проход по полям объекта-источника "вглубь" до уровня примитивов, и их присвоение соответствующим полям объекта-цели
- статичный метод [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

Примеры ниже - демонстрируют второй подход, как наиболее простой и компактный.

---

Копирование полей только тех объектов, которые присутствуют в первом массиве:

```js
var array1 = [
  { name: "dima" }
];

var array2 = [
  { name: "dima",  age: 22, notes: "test0" },
  { name: "oleg",  age: 27, notes: "test1" },
  { name: "vasja", age: 44, notes: "test2" }
];

function objArrMerge(target, source) {
  const findTargetObj = n => target.find(o => o.name === n);
  let tObj;
  for (let i = 0; i < source.length; i++) {
    if (source[i].name && source[i].name.length && (tObj = findTargetObj(source[i].name)))
      tObj = Object.assign(tObj, source[i]);
  }
}

objArrMerge(array1, array2);
document.body.style.cssText = 'font: 14px monospace; white-space: pre;';
document.body.textContent = 'array1:\n' + JSON.stringify(array1, null, 2);
```

---

Копирование полей всех объектов (если в первом массиве объект отсутствует - он будет создан):

```js
var array1 = [
  { name: "dima" }
];

var array2 = [
  { name: "dima",  age: 22, notes: "test0" },
  { name: "oleg",  age: 27, notes: "test1" },
  { name: "vasja", age: 44, notes: "test2" }
];

array1 = Object.assign(array1, array2);

document.body.style.cssText = 'font: 14px monospace; white-space: pre;';
document.body.textContent = 'array1:\n' + JSON.stringify(array1, null, 2);
```

Comment: И за что минус ответу? о_О

Answer (score -2):

можно сделать так:

```
for(i=0; i < array1.length;i++) 
{
 if(array2[i].name == array1[i].name)
 {
  array1[i] = array2[i];
 }
}
```

Comment: `array1[i] = array2[i];` - по идее, это создает ссылку на объект, вместо его переноса в `array1`... Если так, то это чревато непредсказуемым поведением в случае когда мемори менеджер решит грохнуть `array2` (а он, злодей, это вполне могёт).

Comment: можно испульзовать еще одну переменую чтоб сохронить результат. Вопрос был в том как объединить 2 массива в один

Comment: Дело не в переменных, а в том что присвоение объектов происходит **по ссылке** (не по значению!). _"Вопрос был в том как объединить 2 массива в один"_ - о том и речь: задача **объединить**, а не создать в массиве ссылку на другой массив... Посмотрите наглядно: http://jsbin.com/rugafakumi/edit?js,output